# Eclipse indigo PDT 3.0 gotcha

Tags: php, new-operator, eclipse-pdt

I understand PDT is not a part of Eclipse Indigo. 
I installed from Help > Install new software and restarted. Still, I do not see PHP as an option in Perspective. Only Java is seen.
Can anyone help in getting me on PHP development with Indigo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it should really be that simple.

- download ["Eclipse Classic"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
- unzip/install to a new folder location (e.g. c:\eclipse-indigo-win32\
- go to help->install new software
- select Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo from the "Work with" drop down list
- type "php" in the filter text
- Select "PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature
- select /next/ok/agree/finish etc..
- wait for install and restart when prompted

to check installation version
 - go to help->about then click the "Installation Details" button
 - look for the version next to "PHP Development Tools (PDT) all-in-one SDK v3.0.0"
 - also check "Eclipse SDK" should be 3.7.0

ensure perspective is selected,
 - next to perspective buttons
 - click icon with "+" symbol
 - select "other"
 - highlight "PHP"
 - select "OK, PHP will now be included in the list of open perspectives

Comment: Thanks Ben. I had to uninstall the earlier PDT I uninstalled and installed the way you'd described. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help->Install new Software  menu

Add `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.0/milestones/` in Work with feild and press add button

then Select All button

click next and then finsih

now a prompt will show restart eclipse
press ok

Now php projects can be created