# Eclipse Indigo PDT does not underline syntax errors

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, syntax-error, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-indigo

I installed Eclipse SDK Indigo and then followed the following instructions to install PDT on it:

This is the original solution posted by [ben-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531793/ben-k) link to the topic: [Eclipse indigo PDT 3.0 gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548809/eclipse-indigo-pdt-3-0-gotcha?answertab=active#tab-top)

> ```
> download "Eclipse Classic"
> unzip/install to a new folder location (e.g. c:\eclipse-indigo-win32\
> go to help->install new software
> select Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo from
> ```
>
> the "Work with" drop down list
>       type "php" in the filter text
>       Select "PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature
>       select /next/ok/agree/finish etc..
>       wait for install and restart when prompted
>
> to check installation version - go to help->about then click the
>   "Installation Details" button - look for the version next to "PHP
>   Development Tools (PDT) all-in-one SDK v3.0.0" - also check "Eclipse
>   SDK" should be 3.7.0
>
> ensure perspective is selected, - next to perspective buttons - click
>   icon with "+" symbol - select "other" - highlight "PHP" - select "OK,
>   PHP will now be included in the list of open perspectives

But I am unable to enable the feature of **highlighting the syntax error** for a file which I load in Eclipse without creating a project in it.

Anybody any clue?

P.S. Btw I am a happy user of Eclipse PDT Helios and was able to update that without any problems. Error highlighting is working perfectly in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem after Eclipse update to Indigo during Ubuntu update.

After installing PDT all ".php" source files opened in text editor (instead of php editor) which meant no syntax highlighting or auto-complete was applied (text was grey).

To fix -

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Associations

Entry for "*.php" had text editor listed first.

I deleted entry for "*.php" and re-created it, phpEditor appears first in editor association list.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your sources are **INCLUDED** in PHP Build Path (Right click on project > Properties >  Php Build Path)