# Eclipse Luna EE not highlight mistakes in php

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I wasted my time because of mistake in code - not `substr` but `subsrt` - why Eclipse not highlight mistakes like this?

I have installed PDT:
[image: eclipse PDT]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758786/eclipse-indigo-pdt-does-not-underline-syntax-errors - is this valid for your version too?

Comment: Thank you but no - my php files opening at php editor and when I hover mouse under function I see documentation; When I hover mouse under my mistaken `subsrt` - I just no see pop-up with documentation.

Comment: Did you install PDT? The base Java EE package does not include it.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik Added screenshot - I have installed PDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDT haven't static code analysis. [PDT-Eg core plugin](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/) have now only initial support for classes and unused variables.

As a workaround (still no warnings in code), you can enable internal function highlighting (PHP/Editor/Syntax Coloring).